# Table header data from JSON in Svelte table

Tags: javascript, json, svelte, sveltekit

I'm messing around with Svelte and the sb-admin-svelte project. I'm working with some sample data from an API in JSON and I have it working so far, but my question is how do I get the key items from the JSON data to automatically parse as a table header in the HTML?

This is what I have so far:

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  }
...
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  import Table from "sveltestrap/src/Table.svelte";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let users = [];

  onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    users = await res.json();

    console.log(users);
  });

  const tableHeading = ["ID", "Name", "Username", "email"];
  
</script>

<Table bordered responsive>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {#each tableHeading as heading}
        <th>{heading}</th>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {#each users as user}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.username}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
      </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Which outputs to this:

[image: svelte table]

Which is fine but what I am trying to figure out is how to get the `tableHeading` data from the JSON data (e.g. `"id", "name" "username", "email`) to automatically populate within the `{#each tableHeading as heading}`.

Comment: Just to clarify based on the DataTable example above, it looks like you are properly outputting table headers (ID, Name, etc) using the constants from the `tableHeading` array, and then building the table body with the loop of `{#each users as user}`. Are you saying you want the JSON data as table headers instead of the static table headers you are already using? Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do? [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1cdbc41f4e7946ecaa85cce2e3b51915?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import Table from "sveltestrap/src/Table.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    async function fetchUsers() {
        const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
        return await res.json();
    }   
</script>

{#await fetchUsers() then users}
<Table bordered responsive>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each Object.keys(users[0]).slice(0,4) as heading}
            <th>{heading}</th>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {#each users as user}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.username}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
        </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</Table>
{/await}
```

But why not automatically populate the table content as well, based on a given number of columns [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6df872edfdc441709a003d463ecc95b3?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import Table from "sveltestrap/src/Table.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    async function fetchUsers() {
        const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
        return await res.json();
    }

    const columns = 4

</script>

{#await fetchUsers() then users}
<Table bordered responsive>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each Object.keys(users[0]).slice(0,columns) as heading}
            <th>{heading}</th>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {#each users as user}
        <tr>
            {#each Object.values(user).slice(0,columns) as value, index}
                {#if index===0}
                    <th scope="row">{value}</th>
                {:else}
                    <td>{value}</td>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</Table>
{/await}
```

For the inner #each loop inside the table body the new [svelte:element](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-element) could be used instead (but not really the better option in this case)

```html
{#each Object.values(user).slice(0,columns+1) as value, index}
    <svelte:element this={index === 0 ? 'th': 'td'}
                    scope={index === 0 ? 'row' : undefined}
                    >
        {value}
    </svelte:element>
{/each}
```

But a more flexible and convenient way would be to populate everything, like you already did, by a defined tableHeading and fill the table body based on that. Like this unwanted values can simply be omitted and the order easily changed [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7d012f7b157644d4ac5aa41997425617?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import Table from "sveltestrap/src/Table.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    async function fetchUsers() {
        const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
        return await res.json();
    }

    const tableHeading = ["ID", "Name", "Website", "email", "Username", "Phone"];

</script>

{#await fetchUsers() then users}
<Table bordered responsive>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each tableHeading as heading}
            <th>{heading}</th>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {#each users as user}
        <tr>
            {#each tableHeading as key, index}
                {@const k = key.toLowerCase()}
                {#if index===0}
                    <th scope="row">{user[k]}</th>
                {:else}
                    <td>{user[k]}</td>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</Table>
{/await}
```

Comment: Ok great! Yeah, I wasn't sure on what the "best" approach would be. I guess my thinking is that if I could dynamically fetch the key values with the data that would be something to not have to worry about in case something would have changed within the data. But now that I look at it some more, I do feel that you are right by defining the `tableHeading` and omitting the unwanted values. Thanks!